# I receive the error "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException" upon compiling this code

Tags: java, input

This is a very simple code, with the purpose being to accept a user-inputted float then convert and return it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaConversionCalculator{

  public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Java Conversion Calculator.");
    System.out.println("This program will convert feet to meters.");
    System.out.print("Enter the number of feet you need to convert: ");

    float feet = scan.nextFloat();

    float meters = (feet / 3.2808f);

    System.out.println(feet + " feet is equal to " + meters + " meters.");
    System.out.println("Goodbye");

  }

}
```

This is the feed when I try to compile and execute:

```
Welcome to the Java Conversion Calculator.
This program will convert feet to meters.
Enter the number of feet you need to convert: Exception in thread "main"
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Scanner.java:2345)
    at JavaConversionCalculator.main(JavaConversionCalculator.java:20)
```

Comment: The scanner didn't like your input.  What did you type in?

Comment: @ajb it didn't allow me to input. It got upset at me before I was able to type anything in at all.

Comment: How you are compiling it? Some IDE or Terminal/Command prompt?

Comment: @ajb If it didn't like the input, it would have thrown `InputMismatchException` according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextFloat()).

Comment: @4castle Doc -u- man ... uh, what's that?  :) :)  (Ok, I didn't check the javadoc to see if it was the right exception.  Sorry.)

Comment: Your IDE must not have the standard input stream connected to the console. Is there a file it reads input from?

Comment: @CS_noob I'm using https://www.compilejava.net/. I don't have the ability to get anything else working on this computer atm.

Comment: @4castle It's intended to be standard keyboard input.

Comment: @GDaniels It looks like that website doesn't support console input. You have to use command line arguments. (You can read those from `args` in your `main` method)

Comment: @4castle Since the program worked as intended for user3502783, I think it should be fine as-is.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]){
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Welcome to the Java Conversion Calculator.");
System.out.println("This program will convert feet to meters.");
System.out.print("Enter the number of feet you need to convert: ");

if(scan.hasNextFloat()){
    float feet = scan.nextFloat();
    float meters = (feet / 3.2808f);
    System.out.println(feet + " feet is equal to " + meters + " meters.");
 }

System.out.println("Goodbye");

}
```

Try this to know weather scan is getting element or not.

Answer (score -1):

The program expects a floating point value as input but there is no input to read from. Hence `nextFloat()` fails.

Kindly check if the IDE you are using accepts Standard input. If not use another IDE.

Comment: given the comments, this cannot be the right answer.  Or if it is, it isn't helpful because it doesn't tell him how he can get input into the program.

Comment: I felt the answer to java.util.NoSuchElementException is what I have mentioned. Hence added it as an answer.

Comment: @OP: kindly use any online complier that supports standard input. Such as IDEOne